# Reduction of morphisms with connected fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper morphism of notherian schemes over a DVR $R$, $Y$ being a smooth connected scheme. Assuming te generic fiber of $f_K:X_K\rightarrow Y_K$ to be connected (even smooth connected), where $K=Frac(R)$, is it true that the generic fiber of $f_k:X_k\rightarrow Y_k$ is also connected?
It seems that applying Stein factorization gives this result but I am not sure of my interpretation.